# Python Youtube Video Downloader using link

Tags: python, pytube, customtkinter

I built a Python project using **pytube and custom tkinter** and whenever I paste a youtube link to be converted into video it gives me my custom made command `Download Error`

here's the entire code:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from pytube import YouTube

# Youtube/Pytube Library

def startDownload():
    try:
        ytLink = link.get()
        ytObject = YouTube(ytLink, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
        video = ytObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        title.configure(text=ytObject.title, text_color="white")
        video.download()
        finishLabel.configure(text="Downloaded!")
    except:        
        finishLabel.configure(text="Download Error", text_color="red")

def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    per = str(int(percentage))
    progress.configure(text=per + '%')
    progress.update()

    progressbar.set(float(percentage) / 100)

#system settings

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

#Framework

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("720x480")
app.title("DerpyStudios Downloader")

#UI Elements Basics
title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Insert Youtube Link Here")
title.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

#Input

url_var = tkinter.StringVar()
link = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, width=350, height=40, textvariable=url_var)
link.pack()

#Download

download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Download", command=startDownload)
download.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

#Progress

progress = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="0%")
progress.pack()

progressbar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(app, width=400)
progressbar.set(0)
progressbar.pack(padx=10, pady=10)



#Post Download

finishLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="")
finishLabel.pack()

#loop
app.mainloop()
```

and thats all the code it was just in a regular `.py` file.

The image of the program is linked below:

[here's the gui + error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKFsK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. That is indeed an error mesage but it's not helpful at all. Could you add a `print` statement in the `except` block?

Answer (score 1):

i found this ... it's working with  me

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from pytube import YouTube

# UI Design and Settings 
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System") # Set the appearance based on   the system 
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

# Frame Settings 
application = customtkinter.CTk() # Initialize the application 
application.geometry("800x400")
application.title("YouTube Video Downloader")

# Add in UI elements
title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(application, text="Paste a YouTube video link")
title.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

def startDownload():
    try:
        linkToDownload = youtubeLink.get()
        youTubeVideoObject = YouTube(linkToDownload,     on_progress_callback=inProgress)
        video = youTubeVideoObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        video.download()
        videoTitle = youTubeVideoObject.title
        statusMessageText = customtkinter.CTkLabel(application, text="The  video:" + videoTitle + " is downloaded!", text_color="green") 
        statusMessageText.pack(padx=25, pady=25)
    except:
        statusMessageText = customtkinter.CTkLabel(application, text="The link:" + linkToDownload + " is invalid!", text_color="red")
        statusMessageText.pack(padx=25, pady=25)

def inProgress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    totalSize = stream.filesize
    bytesDownloaded = totalSize - bytes_remaining
    percentageOfCompletion = bytesDownloaded / totalSize * 100
    percentageOfCompletion = str(int(percentageOfCompletion))
    # Update Percentage
    progressPercentage.configure(text=percentageOfCompletion + "%")
    progressPercentage.update()
    #Update Progress Bar
    progressBar.set(float(percentageOfCompletion) / 100)

# Textbox input
youtubeURL = tkinter.StringVar()
youtubeLink = customtkinter.CTkEntry(application, width=400, height=50,     textvariable=youtubeURL)
youtubeLink.pack()

# Progress Percentage 
progressPercentage = customtkinter.CTkLabel(application, text="0%")
progressPercentage.pack()

# Progress Bar
progressBar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(application, )
progressBar.set(0)
progressBar.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

# Download Button 
downloadButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(application, text="Download",     command=startDownload)
downloadButton.pack(padx=15, pady=15)

application.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://github.com/Abhay2412/YouTubeDownloaderPython/blob/main/youtubeDownloaderGUI.py

Answer (score 0):

It is documented here and on GitHub that the YouTube API has changed. The pytube developers are aware of the issue, but have not released a new version yet. This seems to happen quite often. Just watch for a new release of pytube greater than 15.0.0

Comment: i was using pytube 15.0.0 exactly

Comment: @DaDerpyBoi I recently switched to 15.0.0 for the same reason, but the API changed again a few weeks ago and caused the current failures. Hopefully there’ll be a new release sometime on.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this:

download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Download", command=startDownload)

for this:

download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Download", command=lambda: startDownload())